# Voronoi diagram bound by circular tour

Tags: c, computational-geometry, voronoi

I'm facing the following problem:
I'm given a point cloud P and a subset of that point cloud B. The nodes b in B constitute the boundary of the (whole) point cloud P. (In fact, B is given as a closed, oriented circular tour). Now, I would like to compute the Voronoi diagram of P, intersected by B, and extract the Area of each (intersected) Voronoi polygon. Here is an illustration of the situation:
[image]
<sub>(source: [666kb.com](http://f.666kb.com/i/cshix1s881107ghfw.png))</sub>

Basically I would like to intersect the blue polygons with the green segments. 
To my questions:

- Is there, by chance, a C library that solves this exact problem?
- If not, is there a better way to solve this problem then computing the Voronoi diagram using some Library, then explicitly intersecting the (green) segments with the polygons from the library output? Maybe by exploiting a constrained Delaunay triangulation?

PS: I know that this feat would probably be possible using CGAL. However, having never used CGAL, CGAL seems quite complex and adapting Example code such as [this](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/index.html#title16) seems far from straight forward. Also, I would strongly prefer a solution in C.

Comment: You can try an alphashape. Its a delaunay triangulation without edges exceeding alpha.

Comment: Can you maybe elaborate a bit how alpha shapes could be used for my purpose?

Comment: :You can also delete the infinity edges but with alphashapes you have the alpha value you can play with. But I think you need a constrained vd even intersection isn't accurate, isn't?

Comment: There is no need for explicitly intersection since intersection point is middle point of segment connecting two boundary points. Voronoi lib, for a point, returns list of segments of point's Voronoi cell. For two neighbouring boundary points, find segment that is in both Voronoi cells and split it with middle point of segment connecting boundary points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I decided to go against alpha shapes since I already know the exact boundary and do not want to fine tune the alpha value to avoid holes in the interior. Instead, I used Ante's comment to come up with an implementation in CGAL. If anyone is interested, it can be found [here][2]. My use of CGAL is probably really clumsy and one can tell that I'm coming from the C world, but it's a start. Test input can be found [here][3] (in.txt) and [here][4] (bnd_ind.txt). A visualization of the output (highlighted cut faces at the boundary) [![][1]][1]  
<sub>(source: [666kb.com](http://666kb.com/i/csphx8ow43habobik.gif))</sub>  
:

Comment: :Can you upload an image? I was cautious because a constraint vd can give other result? The algorithm is different? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Can I upload an image of what? You can check out the source code I ended up with from the link in my answer.

Comment: :I just ask. You can upload an image of the vd? I believe a cdv solves other problems but I don't know how to proof.

Comment: You can see a pricture of my test VD in my first post and a visualization of the output (i.e. the cut voronoi faces highlighted) in my reply

Comment: Please edit the externally hosted code into the post; doing so will make sure it remains useful even if the link breaks. My script [is not allowed to do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344512/4751173) because of potential licensing problems.